# How to run Kafka as non-root user?

Tags: java, linux, apache-kafka, sudo

According to its [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html), Apache Kafka logs to `/tmp/kafka-logs` by default.

Since `/tmp` is owned by `root` in Linux, then to me, this means that you have to run Kafka as `root` in order for it to log to that location correctly. However for security purposes, I don't want it to run as root, and so I'm trying to figure out what my options are. I *believe* I have to choose between the following:

1. Use the `-Dkafka.logs.dir` command-line switch to specify a different location (that isn't owned by root) for logs to be written to; or
2. Modify the system ahead of time (that is, prior to starting Kafka) so that `/tmp/kafka-logs` is owned by the same user as the user that will be starting Kafka (or, in general, making sure the the Kafka user has the correct permissions to r/w/x to that directory); or

Can someone clarify (or correct) that my undertanding of Linux permissions and processes is correct, and that those are my only two options? And of course, if there are any other options that will allow me to run Kafka as non-root, please chime in!

Comment: `/tmp/` is `rwxrwxrwx` on every Linux and UNIX I've ever encountered.

Comment: "/tmp is owned by root in Linux", this may be true, but ownership is not the end-all in FS permissions, check the mode of /tmp as @slim has suggested

Comment: Thanks @rmlan (+1) - please see my question for **slim** below, beneath his answer, regarding differences between Mac and Linux. I have the same question for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 16 root root 32768 Sep 28 16:39 /tmp
```

The first `rwx` means that `/tmp` is readable, writable and executable by its owner (root), the second `rwx` means that it's readable, writable and executable by its group (root), and the third `rwx` means that it's readable, writable and executable by *everyone*. (For a directory "executable" means it can be navigated into).

So your non-privileged user can write log files to `/tmp`. There may be problems if another user has already created their own `/tmp/kafka-logs`.

However, writing logs to `/tmp` is not a sustainable strategy in the long term. Anything goes if this is a personal system, but on a production system you would not expect `/tmp` to have the reserved storage space or the maintenance attention that a directory like `/var/log` has. By its name, you can guess that files in `/tmp` are considered fair game for deletion if space starts running out.

The page you've linked is pretty clear - although there are defaults, their expectation is that as a minimum you supply a properties file containing `broker.id`, `logs.dir` and `zookeeper.connect`.

So, configure whatever log directory you like, writable by your preferred user.

Comment: Thanks @slim (+1) - although I will be running Kafka on a Linuc box, my dev machine is a Mac. On my Mac: `ls -ld /tmp` produces: `lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Mar 12  2016 /tmp -> private/tmp`. **Can you please confirm that this is simply a discrepancy between Linux and Macs?** Thanks again!

Comment: Note the arrow next to /tmp. This indicates that /tmp is, in fact, a symbolic link to another directory (/private/tmp in this case). In the large majority of cases (if not all), a symbolic link's permissions have no bearing on the permissions of the target (/private/tmp). I bet if you do an `ls -ld /private/tmp`, you will see the permissions that slim was referring to.